# Change google maps marker icon directly?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i want to change my google maps marker image directly when some link was click..my default marker image is..

```
var marke = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, 
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title:"Klik disini",
    draggable:true,
    icon:"http://localhost/pinMarker/img_marker.png" });
```

i want to change icon `"img_marker.png"` to be another image...

where can i achieve what i want with javascript?any link discuss about that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The marker class has a `setIcon` method to change the image.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

To change it when you click on a link you will have to store the markers somewhere to access it from the link click event.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/ZJf8e/